# Python Exception Handling IOError

Tags: python, exception, directory

I'm trying to write a simple pything code that will try to open a file that does not exist,  but it will handle the exception buy displaying "Cannot open, no such directory or file"  Anything suggestions on what I'm doing incorrect?

```
import sys

try:

    f = open("h:\\nosuchdirectory\\nosuchfile.txt","w") # do not modify this line

except IOError:
    print('Cannot open, no such directory or file')

f.write("This is the grape file") # do not modify this line

f.close() # do not modify this line
```

The initial piece of code that I started with is:

```
f = open("h:\\nosuchdirectory\\nosuchfile.txt","w" # do not modify this line

f.write("This is the grape file") # do not modify this line

f.close() # do not modify this line
```

Comment: This belongs on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - your code does work, given that the directory doesn't exists.